# Why number at end of loop prints twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm confused on the results of this code.

I can't grasp why it prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4

```
num = 10  
for num in range(5):  
    print(num)  
print(num)
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: Variable scope. You reassign `num` each time in the loop. Setting it to 10 does not really do anything useful

Comment: I was supposed to predict the result of that code, I got the answer wrong, so I wanted to know why.

Comment: Using the website visualise python, it will show you how your code it being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you assigned num to 10 
`num = 10` then you loop through 0 to 4 using the range function `range(5):` Because you are still using the same variable `num` it will change the value of `num` for each iteration.

the last value of the iteration is `4` so its going to print `4` again since you are printing the value of `num` after the whole loop

Answer (score 0):

Here in  last print(num) statement 'num' var holds the latest value of it which is '4' here, so if you remove the line, it will be exactly as you wanna get.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).